# trying to compile a java program in terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I'm just trying to compile a simple hello world file via the terminal.
Here's the code for `Hello.java`:

```
package Hello;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

this is saved in another folder, so in terminal I typed:

`cd code/repositories/java` to navigate to the correct directory (where I saved `Hello.java`)
I next typed `javac Hello.java` and hit return. It compiled without any errors.
I then tried to open the file with `java Hello` and it threw the following exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: Hello/Hello)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247
```

How/why does this happen and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: You need to run the `java` command from the classpath installation directory (up one level)

Comment: so I should just `cd ~` first?

Comment: I also had a second problem (I had to remove `package hello;`), hence "trying to compile a java program in terminal"—terminal wasn't the only problem. The java part was also wrong, so idk if it's an exact duplicate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package is called `Hello` which makes the full qualified name `Hello.Hello` which means you need to have your Hello.java file in `code/repositories/java/Hello`

then cd to the `code/repositories/java` folder and call javac `javac Hello/Hello.java` then you can run it `java Hello.Hello`

On a different note, Java standard naming conventions recommend package names use lowercase letters so consider changing the package to "hello"

Comment: yeah, I realized the lowercase name thing (already changed it to `package hello;`)

Comment: the folder must match the case of the package so if the package is now "hello" then that's what the folder should be called as well

Comment: +1 but you need to compile as `javac Hello/Hello.java`.

Comment: Oh you're right. Fixed typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remove line `package Hello;`. Compile and run.

Comment: awesome, it worked! This was originally written in Netbeans, so I understand the difference (it's just a file without said `Hello` container folder).

Comment: I had the same problem. I also coppied the code from NetBeans.